# Problems with permissions on Google Cloud IAM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have problems assigning roles to a specific user using the Google cloud console IAM.
The user has a gmail account but he is not receive any notification mail every time I try to change his role - we have already checked in spam folder.
So ,the user does not obtain the permission I tried to assign him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you have the correct email address of the Gmail user, and the user is sure that they are able to login to the Gmail account that corresponds to that email address, they should be able to to visit this URL to accept the invitation:

https://console.cloud.google.com/invitation?project=PROJECT_NAME&account=EMAIL&memberEmail=EMAIL

Replace `PROJECT_NAME` with the projectId of the project and `EMAIL` with the gmail.com address of the user in question.

*Note, the user should only have to accept an invitation for the **Owner** role.*